# Android AsyncTask - Order of execution

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am facing an issue regarding the order of exection of AsyncTasks.

My question is :

Assuming I have 2 implementations of AsyncTask : **MyAsyncTask1** and **MyAsyncTask2**

That are called in the following manner :

```java
new MyAsyncTask1 ().execute ();
new MyAsyncTask2 ().execute ();
```

Is it garanteed that **MyAsyncTask1** is executed before **MyAsyncTask2** ?
One thing for sure, they are not executed in parallel since the default executor is used, which is **SERIAL_EXECUTOR**.
The problem lies in the order of execution : which will be executed first ??

If the order of execution is not determined, how can I enforce an order of execution for the AsyncTasks ??

What I need is to have **MyAsyncTask1** executed before **MyAsyncTask2**, which is not always the case, eventhough I am calling execute for **MyAsyncTask1** before **MyAsyncTask2**.

What I actually have is a custom activity :

```
public abstract class CustomActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        new MyAsyncTask2 ().execute ();
    }
}
```

And another activity that inherits from the custom activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends CustomActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        new MyAsyncTask1 ().execute ();
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    }
}
```

So if I use the **MainActivity**, **MyAsyncTask1** should be executed before **MyAsyncTask2**, at least that is the behavior I need.

Comment: start MyAsyncTask2 from `onPostExecute` of MyAsyncTask1 then always MyAsyncTask1 executed before MyAsyncTask2

Comment: Hello imran khan, thank you for your suggestion but this is out of question, due to my design. CustomActivity (and MyAsyncTask2) are used by other activities (using inheritance) where I do not want to call MyAsyncTask1 at all.

Comment: then just pass Activity name to  CustomActivity (and MyAsyncTask2) constructor from which you want to start MyAsyncTask2 or null for other activities from which you does not want to start MyAsyncTask2

Comment: or you can use `context.getPackageManager().getClass();` in CustomActivity (and MyAsyncTask2) to get the name of activity currently viewing by user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to ensure that two threads (that's what AsyncTasks basically are) are executed in the order you want, is to start the second thread when the first one finishes.

In your case, to keep implementation abstracted and not have to actually call AsyncTask2 in the `onPostExecute` of AsyncTask1 (the way Anup and Sanket suggested, which is also fine if you want to mix them), make AsyncTask1 call `super.executeAsyncTask2()`, where `executeAsyncTask2()` is a method in your CustomActivity which starts the second AsyncTask

Comment: Hello zrgiu ! You actually understood my design.
If I am to use your suggestion, then how do you suggest to call MyAsyncTask2 in CustomActivity ? (Other than calling the method you suggested in each sub class)

Comment: since your AsyncTask1 would have to call the method from another class somehow, i don't see any other way. sorry

Answer (score 3):

In order to "chain" any number of AsyncTasks, what I do is have my AsyncTasks recieve a custom Callback as a parameter. You just have to define it like this:

```
public interface AsyncCallback(){
    public void onAsyncTaskFinished();
}
```

Your AsyncTask implementation constructor should have an AsyncCallback as a parameter, like this:

```
private AsyncCallback callback;

public AsyncTaskImplementation(AsyncCallback callback){
    //Do whatever you're doing here
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

Of course if they have more parameters, don't delete them.

Then, just before the end of `onPostExecute`, introduce this:

```
if (callback != null) callback.onAsyncTaskFinished();
```

So, if you pass a callback, the AsyncTask will execute your callback in the main thread. If you don't want to execute any callback, just pass `null`

So, to call your AsyncTask chain you just write this:

```
new AsyncTask1(new AsyncCallback(){

    public void onAsyncTaskFinished(){
         new AsyncTask2(null).execute();
    }

}).execute();
```

I hope this helps you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Call your second Async task at the end of the first Aysnc task (i.e at the end of the `onPostExecute()` method of your first async task)

```
//first async task's onPostExecute method

onPostExecute()
{
//do your stuff and call second async task

new MyAsyncTask2 ().execute ();

}
```

This will guarantee execution of the second task after the first one in a simple and elegant fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Call 2nd Task in onPostExecute of task 1
as

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String string){//String or whatever u passed
    new MyAsyncTask2 ().execute ();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

AsyncTask execute in background so in your case first code will start task1 and immediately start task2.. so call

```
new MyAsyncTask2 ().execute ();
```

this in to postexecute of Task1

Answer (score -1):

Don't make things complicated and try to keep your design simple and clean. The race between your both AsyncTasks depends on the amount of processing they carry inside their overrided methods. Logically, if you want your AsyncTask1 to complete before AsyncTask2, then simply add the code-blocks of your second Async inside the first one.

Or launch your second Async from the **onPostExecute** of your first Async - but personally, that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Hello Waqas. Thanks for your suggestion, but I do believe that my design is simple. The main idea is that : I am using the CustomActivity (using inheritance) in many cases, and each case has its own implementation; CustomActivity holds the common basic part, while each sub class of it adds what is specific. So I cannot simpply add the content of AsyncTask2 into AsyncTask1.